# Need help putting this into an echo statement

Tags: php, escaping, echo

I cant seem to figure out how to change this up to be properly outputted in an echo statement. Can anyone give me a hand with this? Thanks.

`<img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri();  ?>/img/teams/<?= urlencode( $home_team ); ?>.png" alt="<?= $home_team; ?>"  width="86"  />`

Comment: What does that produce and why is that wrong?

Comment: The code works as it stands, but I need to put it within an echo

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/teams/' . urlencode( $home_team ) . '.png" alt="' . $home_team .'"  width="86"  />';
```

or

```
printf('<img src="%s"/img/teams/%s.png" alt="%s"  width="86"  />', get_template_directory_uri(), urlencode( $home_team ), $home_team);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Please accept the answer (click the checkbox to the left of the answer) if it was helpful.